# Term for upward slant of horizontals in a typeface

Tags: typography, typefaces, skew

I've noticed that in a lot of typefaces simulating upright hand lettering, the horizontal strokes slant upward.
In Comic Sans and Comic Neue, this slant is especially visible on the crossbars of lowercase **e** and uppercase **A** and **H**.
So does the **H** in the logo of the Holiday Inn hotel chain.
Apple Casual shows the effect in more horizontals, as do Dom Casual, Wastrel, Blambot Casual, Segoe Print, and Tekton.
In the [Apache/August family](http://www.typophile.com/node/41545) (trade names include Apache URW, Cochise, Disney Print, Jester, Stanley, and Toledo), nearly everything horizontal has a 10% grade or 6 degree skew, including glyph baselines.
The upward slope tendency also appears in ''kaishuu'', or [Japanese "regular" script](http://namakajiri.net/nikki/the-upward-slant-in-eastern-and-western-calligraphy/).

Is there a typographic term for this phenomenon in general?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question and I can't say that I know a simple black and white term for this phenomenon. However, in [this thread](http://typophile.com/node/39175) (a discussion on the fall of the crossbar on the lowercase 'e' from a slanted to horizontal position in the transition of Humanist to Old Style) it is referred to as an oblique crossbar. A term that I think fits.

(Read more about Humanist and Old Style [here](http://ilovetypography.com/2007/11/06/type-terminology-humanist-2/))

As a characteristic it is simply referred to as a slanted (or less often sloping or angled) crossbar in the texts that I have found, texts that are generally discussing the differences between more organic Humanist inspired fonts VS the later Old Style in which the crossbar is horizontal. (e.g [1](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=z7vKG7s1FaUC&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91&dq=why%20slanted%20crossbar%20type&source=bl&ots=FVKM-mjjt6&sig=2oF7QX3gCGTyqMZjG72waGqVlfc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=L7EzVN2BKdfYavSCgcgJ&ved=0CCAQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=why%20slanted%20crossbar%20type&f=false), [2](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FiJ87ixLs0sC&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=why%20slanted%20crossbar%20type&source=bl&ots=iJh8gbIt8u&sig=OJY3WPoo_LsZoGiFfDkbVthXgZ8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=L7EzVN2BKdfYavSCgcgJ&ved=0CCMQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=why%20slanted%20crossbar%20type&f=false), [3](http://www.graphic-design.com/Type/bergsland/humanist.html), [4](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/17/making-sense-type-classification-part-1/))

As you mentioned though, it is a characteristic that is inherent in fonts that are more organic in style and sometimes mimic traits of calligraphy or hand writing. A characteristic that unfortunately can no longer be defined as simply a Humanist or Venetian trait as there are plenty of fonts inspired by both of these that have no angled in their crossbar.

I hope I've helped you get closer to a solid term on this, I would be really interested to know!